# Programmatically activating existing label decorator from another plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a plugin which contributes a label decorator to `org.ui.eclipse.decorators`.
I want this label decorator now to be inactive by default, which is achieved quite straight forward by setting its  `state`-attribute to `false`.

Now to the point of my question:
Is it possible to change the state of this decorator programmatically **from another plugin**?
The User can check and uncheck this decorator from the global preferences, but can this also be achieved by another plugin?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable (or disable) a decorator using:

```java
IDecoratorManager manager = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDecoratorManager();

manager.setEnabled("decorator id", true);
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast! :) Thanks a lot!